# "population in China" vs "population of China"

Tags: prepositions

[From a post](http://China%20urban%20population%20for%202018%20was%20823,827,650)

> **China urban population** for 2018 was 823,827,650 ...

Which seems grammatically incorrect, at least not as common.

According to [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=urban%20population%20in%20China%2Curban%20population%20of%20China%2CChinese%20urban%20population%2CChina%20urban%20population&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Curban%20population%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Burban%20population%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUrban%20Population%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Curban%20population%20of%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CChinese%20urban%20population%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Curban%20population%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Burban%20population%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BUrban%20Population%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Curban%20population%20of%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CChinese%20urban%20population%3B%2Cc0), "urban population in China" are more common while "China urban population" is shown as "Ngrams not found".

[image]

## question 1

Regarding the use in question, is the following sentence more natural than other alternatives?

> The urban population in China for 2018 was 823,827,650 ...

---

[From the Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/population)

> In the past eight years, the elephant **population in Africa** has been halved.

> In 1992 the **population of Cairo** was approximately 6,500,000.

Which seem to demonstrate the usage of prepositions with "population", "in" and "of".

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=population%20in%20China%2Cpopulation%20of%20China&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cpopulation%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpopulation%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPopulation%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPOPULATION%20IN%20CHINA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpopulation%20of%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPopulation%20of%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPOPULATION%20OF%20CHINA%3B%2Cc0#t4%3B%2Cpopulation%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpopulation%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPopulation%20in%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPOPULATION%20IN%20CHINA%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cpopulation%20of%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bpopulation%20of%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPopulation%20of%20China%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPOPULATION%20OF%20CHINA%3B%2Cc0) also shows the use of them

[image]

I am aware that "Chinese population" is much more common, though I'd just like to know the difference between "population in China" and "population of China".

## question 2

Does it involve nationality, citizenship or something else?

Why is "in" more natural than "of" for question 1?

Comment: This question was already asked in EL&U. link [ https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/110928/prepositions-in-or-of-for-referring-to-a-population-of-a-country ]